# (C#) How to make HexDump formating works with TextBox?

Tags: c#, serial-port, hexdump

I have `TextBox` on Windows forms where I successfully receive hex-data from com-port, but it is shown in a line, but I need it to be shown in HexDumpFormat.

What I getting now:

[image: What i getting now]

After searching I found sample code: [Quick and Dirty Hex dump](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36747/Quick-and-Dirty-HexDump-of-a-Byte-Array). This seems like what I need, the TC said that all we need is to paste his function into code of mine, and call this function where we need, but I'm puzzled how exactly to make it work with my code? Much thanks. (I cant attach more then 3 links, therefore you can see on a link page, how HexDump format looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        string rs;
        byte re;
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // Da
        {
            try
            {
                //rs = serialPort1.ReadByte();
                //re = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte());
                rs = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { re });
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(type));
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException) { }
        }
        void type(object s, EventArgs e)              // receive data
        {
            textBox4.Text += rs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want the output exactly as in the link? with the binary value first and then the hex representation splited by a space?

Comment: Actually it doesnt matter so much, thanks for respond.

Comment: With binary would be better, but now im confused a lot, tha it cant do even without binary...

Comment: are the HEX numbers send as a string ? does it look like this: `rs = "0004"` ?

Comment: Acually im sending from microcontroller where code works with 16bit binary, but i configed that MK will output data to com port not in binary but in  .hex. Anyway  I can config it again and send it, as it is - in binary, it will looks like "0000000000000001" for 1, if it will do things easier of cause

Comment: I doubt that it will do things easier to have it binary. Were you able to read it byte for byte?

Comment: and im confused with your question, doesnt "0004" -  hex data?(16 bit)?

Comment: yes, it sends as it is in 16bit value "0000000000000001"

Comment: it is, but it makes a difference whether you get this information as byte b = 0x00 of as string s = "00" because in a string every character is represented by a byte!

Comment: so this string s = "00" would result in 2 bytes. The first being 0x48 and the second being 0x48. have a look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code from the link. This simple example:

```
byte[] byte_array = new byte[5];

byte_array[0] = 0xAC;
byte_array[1] = 0x12;
byte_array[2] = 0xA0;
byte_array[3] = 0xC5;
byte_array[4] = 0x88;

Console.WriteLine(Utils.HexDump(byte_array, byte_array.Length));
```

results in the following output:

[image]

Important is that you specify how many bytes from the array should be printed in 1 line.

You need to get your data from the `SerialPort` into a byte array. I would suggest to try the following code:

```
SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();

byte[] byte_array = new byte[1024];
int counter = 0;

while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
{
    byte_array[counter] = (byte)serialPort1.ReadByte();
    counter++;
}
```

**EDIT**

to be able to use the code from the Link, add a new class file to the project. And copy paste the code inside it. Make sure that the *.cs class file is in the same project as your `Form1` class.

**EDIT 2:**

If you receive the HEX numbers as string. you could just convert it yourself to a byte array and then use the `Utils` class from you link to display it. Here is a small example code to accomplish this:

```
string rs = "0004";   // example from your code

byte[] byte_array = new byte[rs.Length/2]; // array is half as long as your string
int idx = 0; // count variable to index the string
int cnt = 0; // count variable to index the byte array

while (idx < rs.Length-1)
{
    byte_array[cnt] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(rs.Substring(idx, 2), 16);
    idx += 2;
    cnt++;
}
```

Then you can print the result like this:

```
textBox4.Text += Utils.HexDump(byte_array, cnt) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: THanks a lot mate, but how to print the result into textBox4?

Comment: I tried textBox4.Text = (Utils.HexDump(buffer));  but doesnt work

Comment: i got a error that "Utils" and "buffer" doesnt exist in this context

Comment: void type(object s, EventArgs e)           
        {
            textBox4.Text = (Utils.HexDump(buffer));
        }

Comment: have you seen my second example? You need to declare a `byte[]` in your code. Up to now I don't see any. and you need to make a new *.cs File and copy the `Utils` class code inside there. Make sure it is in the same project as your `Form1` class.

Comment: @JeezyWonder I made a second edit with a small example code ho to use the incoming string and convert it into a byte array. so that you can print it into your textbox. Have a look and try it out. Hope it helps

Comment: Question about seconde edit -     As i understood i need to convert expecting all hex values by my self in the project? Or only one to make it work with all of them like the fist one?  I will try your code out, and post a result, much thanks for helping, Mong

Comment: You need to understand that if you want to use the `Utils.HexDump` method, you need to have your data in a byte array. So yes you need to convert the string representation that you receive over the serial port into the byte representation. To do that you can use the second edit. You are welcome. If my answer helped you, you can consider to mark it as accepted.